# Can't dismiss follower

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I seem to have a little problem as I played through the Dragonborn DLC from Skyrim...

Recently I've run into a problem that's beginning to frustrate me...and that is that I have a Riekling hunter as a pet/follower as well as a custom one. I decided that I no longer needed the Riekling for assistance and wanted to dismiss him. So I went through the dialogue to do that and the message says that "my pet went home" or something like that. Problem is...he still follows me around and the dialogue still treats him as a follower!

I'm using Amazing Follower Tweaks but I'm not sure if AFT also works on Rieklings because I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the mod but that didn't do anything, though trying to play the game without the mod caused some very wierd things to happen like slowing my game down to 1 FPS and having the game kind of flash between low and super high brightness.

I've tried setting the Riekling follower to non-essential and tried the console `kill` command on him, which didn't work. I also tried to get a dragon to attack him and kill him, that didn't work, he didn't lose any health at all as if he's invincible. My other custom follower works just fine and as intended. I also tried the `set playerfollowercount to 0` command that only made my custom follower leave. If anybody asks, I did complete the Thirsk Mead Hall quest.

I don't know what else I can do to try get rid of him. I really don't want to be stuck with him for the rest of my playthrough of Skyrim, but at the same time I don't want to restart the game...

If anybody has any ideas or can help please let me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind I figured out how to fix my own problem, it seemed all i needed to do was reset Amazing Follower Tweaks by talking to my functioning custom follower and going through the settings to reset AFT to complete default.

Kind of acted like a reboot function which thankfully automatically dismissed all followers and allowed me to recruit my custom follower back in!

Answer (score 1):

Try one (or both if one doesn't work) of these in the [console](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console);

- `set playerfollowercount to 0`
- click on the follower, type `disable`. Poof. (if you want the creature to still exist try `enable` immediately after, maybe it'll fix itself)