# Cannot get in the castle to lead Serena home

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have successfully gotten through the gate with a glitch, but when I press the button to open the door, nothing happens and I am stuck on the other side of the gate until I eventually load my last quick save.

**I cannot go back to before I met her**, as I did not make saves through the game and would be going back to the beginning. I just want Serena to stop following me. I can’t even trade things with her or tell her to wait somewhere.

Comment: Are you on PC so you can use console commands?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/95920/163757 or https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155468/cant-dismiss-follower

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me aswell. I fixed this by loading a save before I met serena then I went and discovered the castle(her home) with her following you.     If this is confusing then what I mean is, do not have the castle volkihar discovered until serena is following you.

Comment: The OP says they don't have a save from before meeting Serana.